# Heatmap: Get related data of the hovered cell on mouseOver

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to use some external DOM element to display some information when the user hovers over the heatmap cells.

Therefore I'm using the `plotOptions.heatmap.mouseOver` property to register my callback function.

**But, I'm facing problems to fetch the hovered cell's underlying data with the data I get back [from the event](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.heatmap.events)**

As the documentation is stating `this` refers to the complete series within the callback, but how do I know which series' cell was hovered over? `this.points`contains all cells/points of this series but how do I know the correct index of the hovered one? Is this information stated at the hover events at all?

Can somebody help me with that and maybe point me to the correct properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the [`point.events`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.point.events) hook instead:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    point: {
      events: {
        mouseOver: function() {
          var chart = this.series.chart;
          if (!chart.lbl) {
            chart.lbl = chart.renderer.label('')
              .attr({
                padding: 10,
                r: 10,
                fill: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
              })
              .css({
                color: '#FFFFFF'
              })
              .add();
          }
          chart.lbl
            .show()
            .attr({
              text: 'x: ' + this.x + ', y: ' + this.y
            });
        }
      }
    },
    events: {
      mouseOut: function() {
        if (this.chart.lbl) {
          this.chart.lbl.hide();
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
```

Sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1h6e10bk/) using this and heatmap.